# Find the smallest natural number $n$ such that there exists a polynomial $P(x)$ satisfying : $P(x)$ has a real root and $2014 \le a_i \le 2015 $

Tags: inequality, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Find the smallest natural number $n$ such that there exists a polynomial $P(x)$ satisfying :

$P(x)=a_{2n}x^{2n}+a_{2n-1}x^{2n-1}+...+a_0$ has a real root and $2014 \le a_i \le 2015 $ ($ $with $ 0\le i \le 2n )$

Here's all i did :

Let $A$ = $max \frac {|a_k|}{|a_{2n}|} ,  k = 0,1,...(2n-1)$

$P(x) = a_{2n}x^{2n}(1+ \frac{a_{2n-1}}{a_{2n}x} +...+\frac{a_0}{a_{2n}x^{2n}}) $

Let $ P(x)=0.$  If $|x| \le 1 \Rightarrow |x| \le 1+A $

If $|x| > 1 \Rightarrow 1 \le A ( \frac{1}{|x|} + \frac{1}{|x^2|} +...+ \frac{1}{|x^n|} ) \le \frac {A}{|x|.(1-\frac{1}{|x|}) } \Rightarrow 1\le \frac {A}{|x|-1} \Rightarrow |x| \le 1+A  $

So if $x_0$ is a real solution of $P(x)$ , then $|x_0| \le 1 +max \frac {|a_k|}{|a_{2n}|} ,  k = 0,1,...(2n-1) $

$\Rightarrow |x_0| \le 1+ \frac{2015}{2014} $

$2014 \le a_i \le 2015 \Rightarrow x_0 < 0 \Rightarrow x_0 \ge -1 -\frac{2015}{2014}$

This is all i did , i think we need one more evaluation from $x_0$ to find the minimum value of $n$ . I have no more ideas. Looking forward to getting help from everyone. Thanks very much

Comment: Essentially the same as https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1631501/polynomial-with-bounded-coefficients-and-real-root?noredirect=1, with $n\ge 2014$.

Comment: @Macavity The question  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1631501/polynomial-with-bounded-coefficients-and-real-root?noredirect=1 did not solve my problem . Please don't close my question !

Comment: It is the same problem with $2014$ replacing $100$ and is solved there. We obviously can't have a new problem whenever the actual number used is changed, especially if the method to solve is exactly the same. If you have any doubt on the accepted answer that do ask there.

Comment: @Macavity  I'm afraid that after 6 years have passed, the author doesn't remember much about their solution anymore

Comment: OK, will vote to reopen the problem, in case others concur, you will have your clarifications addressed.  You may get answers there as well though even if it was an old problem.

Comment: @Macavity Help me please ! I'm stuck