# Find the smallest natural number $n$ such that there exists a polynomial $P(x)$ : $P(x)$ has a real root and $2014 \le a_i \le 2015 $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Find the smallest natural number $n$ such that there exists a polynomial $P(x)$ satisfying :

$P(x)=a_{2n}x^{2n}+a_{2n-1}x^{2n-1}+...+a_0$ has a real root and $2014 \le a_i \le 2015 $ ($ $with $ 0\le i \le 2n )$

Here's all i did :

Let $A$ = $max \frac {|a_k|}{|a_{2n}|} ,  k = 0,1,...(2n-1)$

$P(x) = a_{2n}x^{2n}(1+ \frac{a_{2n-1}}{a_{2n}x} +...+\frac{a_0}{a_{2n}x^{2n}}) $

Let $ P(x)=0.$  If $|x| \le 1 \Rightarrow |x| \le 1+A $

If $|x| > 1 \Rightarrow 1 \le A ( \frac{1}{|x|} + \frac{1}{|x^2|} +...+ \frac{1}{|x^n|} ) \le \frac {A}{|x|.(1-\frac{1}{|x|}) } \Rightarrow 1\le \frac {A}{|x|-1} \Rightarrow |x| \le 1+A  $

So if $x_0$ is a real solution of $P(x)$ , then $|x_0| \le 1 +max \frac {|a_k|}{|a_{2n}|} ,  k = 0,1,...(2n-1) $

$\Rightarrow |x_0| \le 1+ \frac{2015}{2014} $

$2014 \le a_i \le 2015 \Rightarrow x_0 < 0 \Rightarrow x_0 \ge -1 -\frac{2015}{2014}$

This is all i did , i think we need one more evaluation from $x_0$ to find the minimum value of $n$ . I have no more ideas. Looking forward to getting help from everyone. Thanks very much .

The question  [Polynomial with bounded coefficients and real root](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1631501/polynomial-with-bounded-coefficients-and-real-root?noredirect=1) did not solve my problem . Please don't close my question !

Comment: How does that duplicate not solve the problem?  Just because the numerical bounds are different?

Comment: @lulu   I'm sorry but I feel the answer to that question unclear. Can you be more specific about the answer?

Comment: If you have a question about that solution, why not ask it of the author?  Failing that (or if that author does not respond), ask a clear question about some gap you perceive.

Comment: @lulu  I'm afraid that after 6 years have passed, the author doesn't remember much about their solution anymore